# Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json in project root

Tags: bash, azure, azure-functions, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am running a func as part of my bitbucket pipeline, when i run this command

func azure functionapp publish "" --csharp locally from a terminal of my machine, the publish works fine, however as I am attempting to run this from the BitBucket pipeline, I get an error

```
Unable to find project root. Expecting to find one of host.json in project root.
```

I added the following line to my pipeline just to see where BitBucket is executing this command from

```
pwd
ls -l
```

and it returns the below

```
Deploying functions app code with func...
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun  7 09:16 artifact
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4096 Jun  7 09:16 build
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun  7 09:16 cache
drwxrwxrwt 3 root root  100 Jun  7 09:16 data
drwxrwxrwt 3 root root  100 Jun  7 09:16 ssh
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jun  7 09:16 tmp
```

so indeed, the host.json is missing from root, but this file is checked into my repo so i assumed it should be able to pick it up. When i run the command from a terminal locally, the

```
pwd
ls -l
```

the above lists my project directory and the host.json file is present so that makes sense as to why i am able to publish it locally and not as part of my pipeline.

is there a way to get Bitbucket pipeline to find the host file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default working directory where your repository is checked out is `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build`.

It is not `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent`, so watch out for any `cd ..` or `pushd ..` instructions you might be issuing in your script before that point.

You could try to fix the situation with a `popd` or `cd -` or even `pushd $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR` but I would advise to avoid changing the working directory altogether unless it was indispensable.

Comment: yes the probalem was a pushd, i removed that line and it worked fine, thank you